# How to show $f(z) = \sum_{j=1}^m \min_{\ell = 1, \cdots, q}\| x^j - z^\ell \|$ is NOT convex on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$, $q \geq 2$, and $x^j \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for $j=1, \cdots, m$.

How can we show that the following function $f$ is **not** convex?
$$
f : \mathbb{R^{nq}} = \mathbb{R}^n \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} \\
f(z) = f(z^1, \cdots, z^q) := \sum_{j=1}^m \min_{\ell = 1, \cdots, q}\| x^j - z^\ell \| = \left\| \begin{pmatrix}
\min_{\ell = 1, \cdots, q} \| x^1 - z^\ell \| \\ 
\vdots \\ 
\min_{\ell = 1, \cdots, q} \| x^m - z^\ell \|
\end{pmatrix}  \right\|_1
$$

---

**My work/thoughts so far:**

- The problem is the $\min$ functions, since $f$ would be convex on $\mathbb{R}^{nq}$ if the the $\ell(j)$ were already known (since we'd just have a sum of convex functions).
- I've shown that $f$ is not complex under certain simplifying circumstances. Namely, if $x^j = 0$ for $j= 1, \cdots, m$ and we let $n=1$, $q = 2$. Then we can take $z := (6,8)^T$, $w := (4,2)^T$, and $\lambda := 1/2$, which yields
  $$
  f(\lambda w + (1- \lambda) z) = 5m > 4m = \lambda f(w) + (1-\lambda) f(z).
  $$
  That is, I've shown (Assumptions $\nRightarrow$ $f$ convex). But that's not the same as showing (Assumptions $\Rightarrow$ $f$ NOT convex), which is the goal.
- Also, using the reverse triangle inequality, I can show that for all $\lambda \in (0,1)$, $z = (z^1, \cdots, z^q),w= (w^1, \cdots, w^q) \in \mathbb{R}^{nq}$
  $$
  f(\lambda z + (1-\lambda)w) \geq \lambda f(z) + (\lambda - 1) f(w)
  $$
  But, that's also not what I want.

---

**Provenance of exercise:**

- This problem was left as an exercise to the reader in an optimization text I'm reading (*Grundzüge der Globalen Optimierung* by Stein).
- It's part of an ongoing example about finding $q$ cluster centers (the $z^j$, $j=1, \cdots, q$) among among a data cloud (the $x^j$, $j=1, \cdots, m$). Here $f$ is reasonable choice for the target function that we'd like to minimize.

Comment: So you've already found a counterexample in low dimension, which implies that $f$ cannot be convex. What else do you need?

Comment: @BigbearZzz It seems a different task to show (Assumptions $\nRightarrow$ $f$ convex) vs. (Assumptions $\Rightarrow$ $f$ NOT convex). For example ($f$ is a function $\nRightarrow$ $f$ convex) is clear, but that doesn't mean that ($f$ is a function $\Rightarrow$ $f$ NOT convex). What I'm attempting to show here is (Assumptions above $\Rightarrow$ $f$ NOT convex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z\in\mathbb R^n$ be a point such that $\|x^j-Z\|,\|x^j-2Z\|>\|x^j\|$ for each $j,$ for example $Z=(1+2\max_j\|x^j\|,0,0,\dots,0).$ Then

$$f(0,2Z,2Z,\dots,2Z)=\sum_{j=1}^m\|x^j\|$$
and
$$f(2Z,0,0,\dots,0)=\sum_{j=1}^m\|x^j\|$$
but
$$f(Z,Z,Z,\dots,Z)>\sum_{j=1}^m\|x^j\|$$
which contradicts midpoint convexity of $f.$

I came to this argument by first considering the case where all the $x^j$ are equal, then generalizing.

Comment: This is great! Thanks! But I think (for full generality with an arbitrary norm $\| \cdot \|$) that we'd need to define your $Z$ as $Z := (\frac{1 + 2\max_j\| x^j \|}{\| e^1 \|},0,\cdots,0)$, with $e^1 = (1,0, \cdots,0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. That way we have $\|x^j - Z\| \geq \big| \| x^j \| - \| Z \| \big| = \big| \| x^j \| - \frac{1 + 2\max_j\| x^j \|}{\| e^1 \|} \|e^1\| \big| = \big| 1 + 2\max_j\|x^j\| - \|x^j\| \big| > \|x^j\|$. (If we don't define it like this, we don't necessarily have the desired inequality because there exist norms such that $\|e^1\| \neq 1$.)

Answer (score 0):

*Yesterday I again lost Internet connection, so I wrote my answer offline and didn’t see Dap’s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3084109/71850). It is a bit similar but more simple so I vote to award him by the bounty.*

Your example can be generalized for the general case. Namely, take $M=1+\max_{j=1,\dots,m}\|x^j\| $ and put $z:=2M(6,8,\dots,8)^T$, $w:=2M(4,2,\dots,2)^T$, and $\lambda=1/2$. Then for each $j=1,\dots,m$ we have

$$\min_{\ell=1,\dots, q}\|x^j-z^\ell\|\le \min_{\ell=1,\dots, q}\|x^j\|+\|z^\ell\|= 
\|x^j\|+\min_{\ell=1,\dots, q}\|z^\ell\|\le M-1+12M<13M.$$

So $f(z)<13Mm$. Similarly $f(w)<5Mm$. So $\lambda f(w)+(1−\lambda)f(z)<9Mm$.
On the other hand, if $v=\lambda w+(1−\lambda)z=2M(5,5,\dots,5)$ then for each $j=1,\dots,m$ we have

$$\min_{\ell=1,\dots, q}\|x^j-v^\ell\|\ge \min_{\ell=1,\dots, q}\|v^\ell\|-\|x^j\|= 
-\|x^j\|+\min_{\ell=1,\dots, q}\|v^\ell\|\ge 1-M+10M>9M.$$

So $$f(\lambda w+(1−\lambda))=f(v)>9Mm>\lambda f(w)+(1−\lambda)f(z).$$